# Azure Search Service unable to map collection of complex objects

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I'm using Azure Search .NET SDK to ingest data from Azure SQL Database.

Besides other fields, the database View returns a list of complex objects with the following structure:

```
[
    {
        "AttributeId": 133,
        "Value": "07.02.2023",
        "Attribute": [
            {
                "Id": 133,
                "Name": "Date",
                "DataTypeId": 4
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "AttributeId": 141,
        "Value": "28.01.2023 06:59",
        "Attribute": [
            {
                "Id": 141,
                "Name": "Inspection date",
                "DataTypeId": 5
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And the model I use for mapping (in .NET):

```
public class Entity {
   ...
   public List<Assignment>? Assignments { get; set; }
}

public class Assignment
{
    public int AttributeId { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public Attribute Attribute { get; set; }
}

public class Attribute
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int DataTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

So, even if I have the same structure when the indexer is running the tries to ingest the data, I get the following error:

```
JSON arrays with element type 'Object' map to Collection(Edm.ComplexType)'). The expected type was 'Edm.ComplexType'
```

I presume that the indexer recognizes the database JSON list as an `Object` and cannot be mapped to List (Collection), but I can't understand why and how I can fix this problem.

Has anyone faced the same problem?

Edited:

*Azure SQL Database doesn't have a built-in data type that naturally maps to Collection(Edm.String) fields in Azure Cognitive Search*

So I have to use a `FieldMappingFunction` but from what I found, I can use only their defined functions. None of them are useful in my case because they have `jsonArrayToStringCollection` but I need `jsonArrayTo<COMPLEX>Collection`

Comment: if you`re using azure cognitive search native indexer, maybe you should write your own poll mechanism and push to your index.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for the suggestion, but the SDK doesn't have support for collection of complex list? Or I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to fix the problem. By default (even if you are using SELECT TOP 1), the `FOR JSON AUTO/PATH` clause surrounds the result with square brackets. So, in my case instead of `"Attribute": [{"Id": 141, "Name": "Inspection date", "DataTypeId": 5 }]` I expected to have `"Attribute": {"Id": 141, "Name": "Inspection date", "DataTypeId": 5 }` as I already had in the **Attribute** class.

Answer (score 0):

According to official samples, you should be able to index Assignments. I do think the issue is around List. Try to make it an array instead:

from:

```
public List<Assignment>? Assignments { get; set; }
```

to:

```
public Assignment[] Assignments { get; set; }
```

Source:
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/search-dotnet-getting-started/blob/master/DotNetHowTo/DotNetHowTo/Hotel.cs

Comment: I have tried this as well, but the error persists :(

Comment: make sure you're using the correct SDK version and also your assignment model has SearchableField attributes

Comment: I'm using `Azure.Search.Documents` v11.4.0 and the Assignment model is declared as follow: `[SearchableField(IsHidden = true)] public Assignment[] Assignments { get; set; }`

Comment: I think the error comes from the way how Azure Search SDK reads the data from the database View. Because from the error message I understand that the JSON array is read is Object instead of Collection(ComplexType)

Comment: try to isolate things first. If native indexer is not working, try to push yourself data. If it works, the issue is around native indexer..

Comment: I removed the "Json" fields and the data were indexed correctly with no error. I don't know exactly what do you mean by native indexer.